# Why is Android Studio failing to install kivy when building an AAB?

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am trying to make an app for android with kivy/python on android studio. The code works compleatly fine, but when i try to build an AAB, i get this error.

error screenshot is in this image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtaVg.png

Versions im using:

python 3.8.10

kivy 2.2.0.dev0

embedded JDK 11.0.13

android grandle plugin version 7.3.1 and grandle 7.4

pls help, i dont know much about android development this is my first app.